# Проблемы при парсинге в facebook

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, facebook

Пытаюсь парсить facebook, но когда я получаю soup, то мне вместо html дерева отдается js код. Кто-нибудь пытался его парсить? Если да, то как вы это делали?

Comment: нет, не пытались

Comment: обоснуйте, пожалуйста, я не так давно этим занимаюсь и здесь за помощью

Comment: покажите ваш код, чтобы мы могли указать на ошибку

Comment: Пытался парсить с помощью PHP-функции file_get_contents(), но что-то ничего не выходит, сайт жёстко защищён и антивирус ругается.